# PHP foreach loop and passing data in Ajax returns 'Undefined index: itemId' - using Ebay API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ebay-api

I want to use Ajax to send an id to a php file. Then I want to use the id in a php function and send the result to the main page. This has to be done by the click of a button.

My Ajax code is working when I use a fixed id, but not if it comes from a loop.

main.php

```
  $('#button').click(function() {
var val1 = $('#itemId').val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: { itemId: val1},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
});  });
```

This php function that I call first. The information comes from the Ebay API.

class_ebay.php:

```
public function findItemsByKeywords($appId,$keyword,$sortOrder,$filterShip)
{

    $apicall   = $this->f_endpoint;
    $apicall .= "OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
    $apicall .= "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0";
    $apicall .= "&SECURITY-APPNAME=". $appId;
    $apicall .= "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-FRCA";
    $apicall .= '&keywords='.$keyword;
    $apicall .= '&sortOrder='.$sortOrder;
    $apicall .= '&itemFilter(0).paramName=Currency';
    $apicall .= '&itemFilter(0).paramValue=CAN';
    $apicall .= '&itemFilter(1).name=FreeShippingOnly';
    $apicall .= '&itemFilter(1).value='.$filterShip;
    $apicall .= '&itemFilter(3).name=Condition';
    $apicall .= '&itemFilter(3).value(0)=New';
    $apicall .= '&itemFilter(3).value(1)=1000';
    $apicall .= '&itemFilter(3).value(2)=1500';
    $apicall .= '&itemFilter.name=ListedIn';
    $apicall .= '&itemFilter.value=EBAY-ENCA';
    $apicall .= '&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=20';

    $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

    if ($resp->ack == "Success") {

        foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {


            $pic   = $item->galleryURL;
            $link  = $item->viewItemURL;
            $title = $item->title;
            $itemId = $item->itemId;
            $paymentMethod = $item->paymentMethod;
            $categoryName = $item->primaryCategory->categoryName;
            $shipping = $item->shippingInfo->shippingType;
            $shippingCost = $item->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost;
            $ConvertPrice = $item->sellingStatus->convertedCurrentPrice;

            ?>

                <table class='table' width='100%'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Selection</td>
                        <td>Image</td>
                        <td>Titre</td>
                        <td>ItemId</td>
                        <td>Prix</td>
                        <td>Action</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""></td>   

                        <td><img src=<?php echo $pic ?>></td>
                        <td><a href=<?php echo $link ?>><?php echo $title ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $itemId ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $ConvertPrice ?></td>


                        <td><button id="button"> Detail </button></td>



                    </tr>
                </table>

           <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="<?php echo $itemId ?>">

                           <div id="result" class="col-md-6"></div> 

         <?php 
            }
        }

}
```

And the ajax.php file, where I get an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: itemId;

```
$itemId = $_POST['itemId'];


    $apicall  = "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?";
    $apicall .= "callname=GetSingleItem";
    $apicall .= "&version=799";
    $apicall .= "&appid=MingLung-research-PRD-02f839365-73d0da39";
    $apicall .= "&siteid=210";
    $apicall .= "&itemid=$itemId";
    $apicall .= "&responseencoding=XML";
    $apicall .= "&IncludeSelector=Description,Details,ItemSpecifics,ShippingCosts,TextDescription,Variations,Compatibility";

    $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

    $Qte = $resp->Item->Quantity;
    $Qtevendu =$resp->Item->QuantitySold;
    $dispo = $Qte - $Qtevendu;
    $itemId = $resp->Item->ItemID;

            ?>

            <div class="panel">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                            <li><a href="#info1" data-toggle="tab">Info 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#info2" data-toggle="tab">Info 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#info3" data-toggle="tab">Info 3</a></li>

                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active well" id="info1">
                                <table class='table' width='100%'>
                                    <tr>            
                                        <td>Prix Affiché</td>
                                        <td>Description</td>
                                        <td>Shipping cost</td>

                                     </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resp->Item->ConvertedCurrentPrice ?>"></td>
                                        <td><textarea name="" class="form-control" ><?php echo $resp->Item->Description; ?></textarea></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resp->Item->ShippingCostSummary->ShippingServiceCost ?>"></td>
                                     </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane well" id="info2">
                                <table class='table' width='100%'>
                                    <tr>            
                                        <td>Type de Shipping</td>
                                        <td>Etat de l'article</td>
                                        <td>Quantité disponible</td>
                                        <td>Localisation de l'item</td>
                                     </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resp->Item->ShippingCostSummary->ShippingType ?>"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resp->Item->ConditionDisplayName; ?>"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $dispo; ?>"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resp->Item->Location; ?>"></td>
                                     </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane well" id="info3">
                                <table class='table' width='100%'>
                                    <tr>            
                                        <td>Seller Shop name</td>
                                        <td>Seller Info Score</td>
                                        <td>Seller PositiveFeedBack Percent</td>
                                     </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resp->Item->Storefront->StoreName; ?>"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resp->Item->Seller->FeedbackScore; ?>"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resp->Item->Seller->PositiveFeedbackPercent; ?>"></td>
                                     </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php
```

This is the resulting error:

[image: Error]

I call another Ebay API function in ajax.php, because I need more specific information about the product.

I really don't understand what's happening and I can't find anything to help me. I am sure I have a problem in the Ajax code. Could you help me find it? Thanks!

Comment: where is the HTML with the button and itemId info in it?

Answer (score 0):

Undefined index means $item->itemId is not defined in the $item element the loop is looking at. Is it perhaps itemID? Try a print_r() or var_dump() on each $item as the loop hits it, and examine the structure to see if itemId actually exists, and if you have a simple capitalization error.

Answer (score 0):

Look here

```
$apicall .= "&itemid=$itemId";
```

Since the parameter name you pass is `itemid`, I suppose that this is the value you need, so, you probably need the following:

```
$itemId = $item->itemid;
```

If you are interested to know what you have in your `$item`, you can check it out by `var_dump`-ing it. You can also convert it into an `array` if you believe it can help you:

```
json_decode(json_encode($item));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned any `id` to your `input` element.

```
<input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="<?php echo $itemId ?>">
```

But you are trying to access the value through jQuery's `id` selector

```
var val1 = $('#itemId').val();
```

The above returns `undefined` and when you add the value to your Ajax call it will be empty

```
data: { itemId: val1},
```

Therefore when you access the value in PHP you will get an `Undefined index` error as the value is missing from POST request

```
$itemId = $_POST['itemId'];
```

Make sure to add the `id` to your `input` so the value can be accessed. Also to prevent the error you can verify the value exists in POST using `isset`.

```
if (isset($_POST['itemId'])) {
    $itemId = $_POST['itemId'];
}
```